# Save geodataframes from list to separate shapefiles

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, iterator, geodataframe

I have a list of geodataframes which I imported from a folder full of shapefiles:

```
import glob
import geopandas as gpd
shapefiles = glob.iglob('E:/folder/shapefiles/*.shp')

gdfs = [gpd.read_file(file) for file in shapefiles]
```

I then clipped them all:

```
clipped = [gpd.clip(shapefiles, boundary) for shapefiles in gdfs]
```

Now I need to save each geodataframe (list item) from the list to a shapefile of its correct name in an output folder. I used this code to create another list called filenames of the shapefiles names with the .shp at the end:

```
filenames = []
for names in items:
    if names.endswith(".shp"):
        filenames.append(names)
print(filenames)
```

But I dont know how to save each item in the clipped list of geodataframes using its corresponding name from the filenames list

Basically I want to perform this task:

```
clipped[0].to_file("E:/test_output/"+filenames[0])
clipped[1].to_file("E:/test_output/"+filenames[1])
clipped[2].to_file("E:/test_output/"+filenames[2])
```

etc etc

But to perform it iteratively and automatically. I need something like this:

```
for things in clipped:
    things.to_file("E:/test_output"+(for stuff in filenames return filenames[]))
```

but with correct syntax and that actually works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
import geopandas as gpd
import os

frames = [gpd.read_file(r'C:\GIS\data\testdata\ak_riks.shp'), gpd.read_file(r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\ak_riks_2.shp")]
names = ['r1.shp','r2.shp']

outfolder = r'C:\GIS\data\testdata'

for frame, name in zip(frames, names):
    frame.to_file(os.path.join(outfolder, name))
```